# place div in right lower corner

Tags: css

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
.a {
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: green;
}
.b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.c {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

I now need to place a in the left upper corner and b on top of c on the right side.

my first solution was to do this:

```
.a{
float: left;
}
.b{
float:right;
}
.c{
float:right;
}
```

the problem is now that c is left of b, but needs to be below it...
Is there any solution for the problem, even when a has a different height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION USING CSS + HTML**

You could place `b` and `c` in a containing div (`#container`), and then `float:right` `#container`.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
    float: left;
}

#container {
    float: right;
}
```

### JS Fiddle Example

---

---

**SOLUTION USING ONLY CSS**

If you cannot change the HTML of the page (or would prefer not to), this can be accomplished with pure CSS by using absolute positioning.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.b {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 0;
}

.c {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 150px; /* or bottom:0 */
}
```

### JS Fiddle Example (using `position:absolute`)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="rightside">
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
    <div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.a {float: left}
.rightside {float: right}
.clear {clear: both}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```